# AsyncCalls - Execute method in main thread under 64bit

Tags: delphi, asynchronous, 64-bit

I have now some problems with AsyncCalls library. My code snippet is expected to execute in a method in main thread.

```
procedure MustExecInMainThread(out Result: ISuperObject); // Sorry, the parameter cannot be changed
var
  SwitchThread: Boolean;
begin   
  SwitchThread := Windows.GetCurrentThreadId <> MainThreadID;
  if SwitchThread then
    EnterMainThread;
  try
    ExecAndReturnResultsAsOutParam(Result);
  finally
    if SwitchThread then
      LeaveMainThread;
  end;
end;
```

It works in 32bit environment perfectly. As the `EnterMainThread` and `LeaveMainThread` is not compatible with 64bit compiler, I tried to convert the code to 64bit compiler compatible. Now the code is able to be compiled, but will raise AV exception at `function CheckSynchronize(Timeout: Integer = 0): Boolean;` (System.Classes.pas)

```
procedure MustExecInMainThread(out Result: ISuperObject);
var
  ResultTemp: ISuperObject;
begin
  TAsyncCalls.VCLSync(procedure
  begin
    ExecAndReturnResultsAsOutParam(ResultTemp);
  end);
  Result := ResultTemp;
end;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Asnyc calls uses a lot of hardcore asm that is 32 bit specific. It for sure does not support 64 bit. So the most obvious conclusion is that your port to 64 bit is broken. Since you did not reveal that part of your work, there's not much chance of anyone giving you specifics on it. What's more I suspect that a port to 64 bit might be intractable due to the vastly different ABI on x64. I think your goal of running AsyncCalls under x64 is doomed to fail. Use OTL instead.

Comment: Asynccalls 2.99 supports 64-bit.  { Version: 2.98 (2011-10-22)                                                                       }
{   Added: Support for Delphi XE2 64bit

Comment: Andreas mentions [here](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/bugfix-units/asynccalls-29-asynchronous-function-calls/) that EnterMainThread/LeaveMainThread are no longer supported by newer Delphi versions

Comment: One wonders why you are using `AsyncCalls` to effect a synchronous call.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, After having read the response of "LU RD", I think TThread meets my requirement already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EnterMainThread/LeaveMainThread is not supported by [`AsyncCalls`](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/bugfix-units/asynccalls-29-asynchronous-function-calls/) anymore for newer Delphi versions.

In order to accomplish the execution of your procedure in the main thread, do something like this:

```
procedure MustExecInMainThread(out Result: ISuperObject); // Sorry, the parameter cannot be changed
var
  SwitchThread: Boolean;
  ResultTemp: ISuperObject;
begin   
  SwitchThread := Windows.GetCurrentThreadId <> MainThreadID;
  if SwitchThread then begin
    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        ExecAndReturnResultsAsOutParam(ResultTemp);
      end
    )
    Result := ResultTemp;
  end
  else  
    ExecAndReturnResultsAsOutParam(Result);
end;
```

Comment: Is it necessary to do a SwitchThread test for TThread.Syncrhonize?

Comment: [`TThread.Synchronize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) must not be called from the main thread. `Warning: Do not call Synchronize from within the main thread. This can cause an infinite loop.` So yes, you have to check before calling.

Comment: I think the warning is for non-static synchronize method. I have double checked the source code, the static method TThread.Synchronize will handle the code differently, if the current thread is main thread or not.

Comment: In this case I would follow the recommendation from the docs. Playing safe here will not cause any performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still using AsyncCalls after migrating my application to 64-Bit. I used LocalVclCall from an async thread to update a progress bar on the main form which is not supported any more under 64 bit.
I was happy to find out that TAsyncCalls.VCLInvoke will do the trick, too. I just call

```
 TAsyncCalls.VCLInvoke(
    procedure
    begin
      DoVCLStuffHere
    end)
```

I haven't noticed any (more) problems under 64 bit than in those 32 bit days.